# Converting list of list in json and use it in jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

I have a structure like this

```
 public class CJsonFeatureQuestion
 {
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
 }
 public class CJsonFeatureProps
 {
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<CJsonFeatureQuestion> FeatureQuestion;
    public CJsonFeatureProps()
    {
        FeatureQuestion = new List<CJsonFeatureQuestion>();
    }
}
```

and sending it to the converting it to json with the help of

```
JavaScriptSerializer
```

to change it into json.

will it work or not.
I am unable to loop through the inner collection in jquery.

### update 1

```
 success: (function Success(data, status) {
                $("#loading").hide();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var innerData = data[i];
                    for (var j = 0; i < innerData.length; j++) {     
                   }
                }
            }),
```

`innerData` is `object Object` but length is undefined.

### update 2

jquery call

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "json",
```

Comment: Should work fine, please post how you're looping through on your client-side. Also note, with the above code, there are no CJsonFeatureQuestion objects populated.

Comment: Have you set dataType to json on the AJAX request? Can you provide the JSON result?

Comment: alert(JSON.stringify(data)); should allow you to see the object you're trying to iterate over. The console of Chrome or Safari's developer tools and Firefox's firebug add-on will also allow you to view the variable. Once you know what you're getting back you'll be able to adjust your algorithm accordingly.

Comment: I found the problem I am posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the inner loop

```
for (var j = 0; i < innerData.length; j++) {     
}
```

It should be as

```
 for (var j = 0; j < data[i].FeatureQuestion.length; j++) {
 }
```

Problem the inner loop was working for every data in list. But only one property was of type list. 
So I looped on that property only and bang...

It started working.